# Check if a string contains one of 10 characters

Tags: c#, string

I'm using C# and I want to check if a string contains one of ten characters, *, &, # etc etc.

What is the best way?

Comment: Do you want to see if any of the characters are there, or if it contains "one" (ie: Exactly one) of those characters, and only one?

Answer (score 250, accepted):

The following would be the simplest method, in my view:

```
var match = str.IndexOfAny(new char[] { '*', '&', '#' }) != -1
```

Or in a possibly easier to read form:

```
var match = str.IndexOfAny("*&#".ToCharArray()) != -1
```

Depending on the context and performance required, you may or may not want to cache the char array.

Comment: When instantiating the char array, the type may be omitted and it will be inferred.

Answer (score 47):

As others have said, use IndexOfAny. However, I'd use it in this way:

```
private static readonly char[] Punctuation = "*&#...".ToCharArray();

public static bool ContainsPunctuation(string text)
{
    return text.IndexOfAny(Punctuation) >= 0;
}
```

That way you don't end up creating a new array on each call. The string is also easier to scan than a series of character literals, IMO.

Of course if you're only going to use this once, so the wasted creation isn't a problem, you could either use:

```
private const string Punctuation = "*&#...";

public static bool ContainsPunctuation(string text)
{
    return text.IndexOfAny(Punctuation.ToCharArray()) >= 0;
}
```

or

```
public static bool ContainsPunctuation(string text)
{
    return text.IndexOfAny("*&#...".ToCharArray()) >= 0;
}
```

It really depends on which you find more readable, whether you want to use the punctuation characters elsewhere, and how often the method is going to be called.

---

EDIT: Here's an alternative to Reed Copsey's method for finding out if a string contains *exactly one* of the characters.

```
private static readonly HashSet<char> Punctuation = new HashSet<char>("*&#...");

public static bool ContainsOnePunctuationMark(string text)
{
    bool seenOne = false;

    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        // TODO: Experiment to see whether HashSet is really faster than
        // Array.Contains. If all the punctuation is ASCII, there are other
        // alternatives...
        if (Punctuation.Contains(c))
        {
            if (seenOne)
            {
                return false; // This is the second punctuation character
            }
            seenOne = true;
        }
    }
    return seenOne;
}
```

Comment: I suppose it's worth caching the char array if performance is a problem, but then again it may not be worth it depending on the context.

Comment: Yes, if you're only using it in a method that's going to be executed once it may not be worth it. However, I think it improves the readability as well as the performance. You could use the `ToCharArray` form "inline" if required, of course.

Comment: @canon: How big is the set? For very, very small sets, I'd expect Array.Contains to be faster. For large sets, HashSet is likely to win by miles.

Answer (score 6):

```
String.IndexOfAny(Char[])
```

Here is [the Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexofany).

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to see if it contains any character, I'd recommend using string.IndexOfAny, as suggested elsewhere.

If you want to verify that a string contains **exactly one** of the ten characters, and only one, then it gets a bit more complicated.  I believe the fastest way would be to check against an Intersection, then check for duplicates.

```
private static char[] characters = new char [] { '*','&',... };

public static bool ContainsOneCharacter(string text)
{
    var intersection = text.Intersect(characters).ToList();
    if( intersection.Count != 1)
        return false; // Make sure there is only one character in the text

    // Get a count of all of the one found character
    if (1 == text.Count(t => t == intersection[0]) )
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yeah - I suppose a single loop is probably faster in this case, especially with the small set of punctuation.  I'd be curious to try testing this with large strings to see which is truly faster.

Comment: I think that finding the intersection of the two strings is going to have to go character by character anyway, so I can't see how it would be faster... and my suggested route not only uses a single pass, but also has the option of an "early out". Imagine if text is a million characters long, but the first two are both "*" :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var specialChars = new[] {'\\', '/', ':', '*', '<', '>', '|', '#', '{', '}', '%', '~', '&'};

foreach (var specialChar in specialChars.Where(str.Contains))
{
    Console.Write(string.Format("string must not contain {0}", specialChar));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you! (And Mainly Jon!):
This allowed me to write this:

```
    private static readonly char[] Punctuation = "$€£".ToCharArray();

    public static bool IsPrice(this string text)
    {
        return text.IndexOfAny(Punctuation) >= 0;
    }
```

as I was searching for a good way to detect if a certain string was actually a price or a sentence, like 'Too low to display'.

Comment: I know this is old, but to be clear this isn't a particularly good way to match currencies... If you had someone write "Ke$ha" it would match as a price... 

Instead refer to one proper way to detect currency defined here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214513/how-to-detect-if-string-is-currency-in-c-sharp