# What is the best way to find out if a string is a roman number?

Tags: c#, integer, roman-numerals

In almost all examples are about converting roman numbers to integer. Does it make sense to convert one by one all roman numbers and then check if that number is a greater than 0?

Comment: Do you have a sample input string which you want to check if it's a roman number? Normally roman numbers uses limited number of alphabets such as I, V, X, C, L D, C M... if your string contains any character other than these, you can consider it as a non-roman number string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390749/check-if-a-string-contains-one-of-10-characters

Comment: There's also the issue that `IIIIIV` is not a roman numeral. You'd have to study the roman numeral system and find the rules of creating numerals.

Comment: have you seen https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/converting-roman-numerals-decimal-lying-1-3999/ ? They have a C# implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you can find anything form the box. 
To create own function :

```
private static Dictionary<char, int> _romanMap = new Dictionary<char, int>
{
   {'I', 1}, {'V', 5}, {'X', 10}, {'L', 50}, {'C', 100}, {'D', 500}, {'M', 1000}
};


public static int IsRoman(string text) {
  foreach (var c in text) 
      if (!_romanMap.ContainsKey(char))
          return 0;
   return 1 
 }
```

Comment: This falls apart when you input `IIIIIV`, as it is not a Roman numeral.

Comment: @Madelaine - Now I see, JMadelaine says absolutely right.

Comment: You are right. Additional validation logic is required. To avoid duplication, check this link out:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900228/roman-numerals-to-integers

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this... Not pretty but...

```
public class Solution {
    public int RomanToInt(string s) {

        var total = 0;
        var currentNumber = 0;
        var lastNumber = 0;
        var lastRoman = '/';

        // Take results from 's' and iterate through chars
        foreach (var roman in s)
        {
            if (roman.Equals('I'))
            {
                currentNumber = 1;
            }
            else if (roman.Equals('V'))
            {
                currentNumber = 5;   
            }
            else if (roman.Equals('X'))
            {
                currentNumber = 10;       
            }
            else if (roman.Equals('L'))
            {
                currentNumber = 50;                 
            }
            else if (roman.Equals('C'))
            {
                currentNumber = 100;          
            }
            else if (roman.Equals('D'))
            {
                currentNumber = 500;  
            }
            else if (roman.Equals('M'))
            {
                currentNumber = 1000;
            }
            // Account for edge cases
            if (roman.Equals('V') && lastRoman.Equals('I') || roman.Equals('X') && lastRoman.Equals('I') || // I can be placed before V (5) and X (10) to make 4 and 9. 
                roman.Equals('L') && lastRoman.Equals('X') || roman.Equals('C') && lastRoman.Equals('X') || // X can be placed before L (50) and C (100) to make 40 and 90. 
                roman.Equals('D') && lastRoman.Equals('C') || roman.Equals('M') && lastRoman.Equals('C') )  // C can be placed before D (500) and M (1000) to make 400 and 900.
            {
                var subtract = currentNumber - lastNumber;                 
                total = total - lastNumber + subtract;                        
            }
            else
            {
                total = currentNumber + total;     
            }

            lastRoman = roman;
            lastNumber = currentNumber;
        }

        return total;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this extensively, but it passed the leetcode check a while back when I wrote it.